# Library, Framework, or Platform to dynamically build workflows (DAG) and validate input/output of tasks before running?

Tags: airflow, workflow, spring-cloud-dataflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am searching for a framework, platform or library that will allow me to implement a set of atomic tasks or operations and store them in a repository. Afterwards, I want to dynamically combine or compose them into larger jobs in the form of directed acyclic graphs. An example could look like the following: Task 1 and Task 2 each produce an output, both of which are consumed by Task 3, and Task 3's output is processed by Task 4.

```
task 1 |
       |--> task 3 --> task 4
task 2 |
```

I've done some digging and there seems to be a flood of different tools that would fit the example above. Apache Airflow, Dagster, Luigi, Spring Cloud Data Flow, etc. among others.

However, so far I have not been able to see how the following use case could be addressed with these tools. I would like to verify that the inputs and outputs of each task match and a meaningful workflow is built before I start executing the workflow. An example that I would like to dynamically compose and validate could look like this:

```
task 1<None, Int> |
                  |--> task 3<(Int, Int), Int> --> task 4<Int, None>
task 2<None, Int> |
```

This job/workflow should validate without problems, since the inputs and outputs of the individual tasks match and the job can be run without problems. Since the job was successfully validated without any problems, it can now be executed.

```
task 1<None, Int>    |
                     |--> task 3<(Int, Int), Int> --> task 4<Int, None>
task 2<None, String> |
```

However, this job/workflow should throw a warning or error before even starting with the execution, since the ouputs of task 1 and task 2 do not match the required input of task 3.

I've seen that many tools support runtime checking of parameters, but this would mean that task 1 and task 2 would already have been executed. Which is something that I would like to avoid. Is it possible to validate the workflow before execution using any of the tools mentioned above or a comparable framework? As the programming languages Java or Python would be preferred, but this is not a strict requirement.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What you're looking for looks more like an ETL, such as [Apache Beam](https://beam.apache.org/) whereas Airflow, Luigi etc. are more Orchestrators.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working with dagster for quite sometime now and it has become a de-facto tool for data-pipeline orchestrations. Yes, you are absolutely right.  the type checking happens at run-time only i.e. before and after the execution of the op/solid. Here is an example dagster snippet (python).

> from dagster import In, Out, graph, op
>
> @op(out={"out_1": Out(dagster_type=int)}) def op_1(_):
> return 10
>
> @op(out={"out_2": Out(dagster_type=str)}) def op_2(_):
> return str(20)
>
> @op(
> ins={"arg_1": In(dagster_type=int), "arg_2": In(dagster_type=int)},
> out={"result": Out(dagster_type=int)}, ) def op_3(_, arg_1, arg_2):
> result = arg_1 + arg_2
> return result
>
> @graph def test_graph():
> op_1_result = op_1()
> op_2_result = op_2()
> op_3(op_1_result, op_2_result)
>
> test_job = test_graph.to_job() test_job.execute_in_process()

- As shown in this example, what I would strongly suggest is to explicitly declare the types of the input and outputs of the ops. This helps in showing informative errors although the type-checking happens only during op execution.
- Each op in this dagster job/pipeline represents a single logical unit operation and ideally I would expect this operation to be a deterministic operation (some sort of data transformation logic) that would yield an output (or data) according to the type defined in the output definition.
- Therefore it is good practice to write ops that perform tasks yielding data of a particular type/schema, rather than having tasks return data that changes types on different runs.
- In this kind of setup, the only time that you'd probably end up re-running the whole dagster pipeline a couple of times due to mismatching types would be probably during the initial setup. Later after the pipeline is developed, it is usually re-run based on a schedule or a sensor in such a way that the code remains the same but the only data changes on each run, however still the ops (if they have deterministic operations) would yield results that conform with type/schema.